# Calling a WebService in setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services

As always, excuse my 'Tarzan' english, please :P

The issue is:
I have to call a webService with time intervals to ensure that a list of contacts is uploaded completely.

The procedure is:
1.-Click on a button to send the CSV file.
2.-A div with a upload animation must bee seen WHILE UPLOADING THE CSV to the database.
3.-When the websService ends entering the data, the div with the unload animation must disappear.

I've created a JS function that ' I Think' is ok, as shown:

```
function loadWS(idArchive){
    $('#loaderX').css('display', 'block');            //Here starts with the animation
    var interrupt=setInterval(function(){             //Start asking the WS
    $.ajax({
        data:{
            'idArchive': idArchive,
        },
        url:'/NewsLetters.checkFinal',                //WebService call: the webservice checks 
        type:'post',                                  //if register entry is complete.
        success:function(res){
            var r=eval(res);
            if(r==1){                                 //IF Response ok? we've finished the task
                clearInterval(interrupt);
                load_sec(link,106);                   //This reloads the section via AJAX
                $('#loaderX').css('display', 'none'); //Here stops the animation
            }
            if (r==0) {
            }
        }
    });
},1000);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it correct to call the WS in the setInterval proc?

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Try it once then if you have any issues, let us know.

Comment: It works fine if I call it one time only. I think problem is recursive or something... responses also are correct...

Comment: 1 sec is quite less I guess. Try to increase the interval.

Comment: just curious why are you using the setInterval to make the ajax call?

Comment: @Charles380, I think the purpose of this ajax call is to check on the server's progress of the processing a CSV into the database. `/NewsLetters.checkFinal` doesn't upload the CSV, it just checks if the server is done processing it.

Comment: WalterStabosz is absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

just do the below and increase time atleast 5 seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        data:{
            'idArchive': idArchive,
        },
        url:'/NewsLetters.checkFinal',                //WebService call: the webservice checks 
        type:'post',                                  //if register entry is complete.
        success:function(res){
            var r=eval(res);
            if(r==1){                                 //IF Response ok? we've finished the task
                clearInterval(interrupt);
                load_sec(link,106);                   //This reloads the section via AJAX
                $('#loaderX').css('display', 'none'); //Here stops the animation
            }
            if (r==0) {
            }
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: but nothing is different

Answer (score 1):

Based on the checking the process you don't need a setInterval you just need to call the function again. I would just do the straight ajax call straight up. Just be careful as it could cause an infinite loop

```
function loadWS(idArchive) {
    $('#loaderX').css('display', 'block'); //Here starts with the animation
    checkStatus(idArchive);
}

function checkStatus(idArchive) {
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            'idArchive': idArchive
        },
        url: '/NewsLetters.checkFinal', //WebService call: the webservice checks 
        type: 'post', //if register entry is complete.
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            // do something with the error
        }
        success: function (res) {
            var r = parseInt(res);
            if (r === 1) { //IF Response ok? we've finished the task                
                load_sec(link, 106); //This reloads the section via AJAX
                $('#loaderX').css('display', 'none'); //Here stops the animation
            } else if (r === 0) {
                setTimeout(checkStatus(idArchive), 1000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I would do. If you really wanted a delay between ajax calls: `if (r == 0) { setTimeout(function() { checkStatus(idArchive); }, 1000); }` . Also, you're probably don't want to be using `eval`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: heh I was doing that just as you made that comment

Comment: My point about eval was actually directed at the OP since it was in his code. I wouldn't even `parseInt`, I'd just do a string comparison `if (r === '1')`.